# code indent and color coding on the Terminal

Tags: macos, terminal

I love programming on the terminal, but am unable to find a way to indent the code that I write down, relegating me to do this laborious task manually. :'( Does everybody else suffer the same fate as me or do you guys have any cool tricks up your sleeve o share with me?

Comment: What editor are you using?  Vim has many included indentation, folding and highlighting plugins for various languages.

Comment: emacs and vim (possibly vi) are both included with OS X, AFAIK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install nano buddy, and realise that osx is a paralysed linux distro:
http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20021017065800302